# JSP/JSTL: Passing a Collection to a Custom Tag

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, custom-tag

I'm trying to implement a custom JSP tag that accepts as an attribute a `Collection` of objects and outputs them as a JSON-formatted array (each object in the `Collection` provides a `getJsonString()` method that returns a JSON-formatted representation of that object).  I have my tag implemented as such:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ attribute name="objects" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" %>
<c:set var="output" value="" />
<c:forEach var="obj" items="${objects}">
    <c:if test="${! empty showComma}">
        <c:set var="output" value="${output}, " /> 
    </c:if>
    <c:set var="output" value="${output}${obj.jsonString}" />
    <c:set var="showComma" value="yes" />
</c:forEach>
[${output}]
```

...and I want to be able to use it by doing something like:

```
<myTaglib:jsonArray objects="${myCollection}" />
```

When I try to use the tag, however, I get a stack trace saying:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'jsonString' not found on type java.lang.String
```

So it's complaining about the `${obj.jsonString}` expression, but I'm definitely not passing a `Collection` of strings.  Moreover, if I change it to `${obj}` I see the correct object types being output, and if I copy/paste the code for my custom tag into the JSP where I want to use it, it works correctly, so I'm really not sure what's going on here.

I assume there is some problem with how I'm passing the `Collection` into the custom tag, but I can't work out what it is.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution, I needed to add `type="java.util.Collection"` to the attribute declaration, as in:

```
<%@ attribute name="objects" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" type="java.util.Collection" %>
```

...I would have thought Java would be smart enough to figure that out on its own, but apparently not.